# Return at the end of every method

Tags: python, methods, return

I was wondering if there is any point in using return at the end of every method.
Is there any down- or upside if you do/don't?

f.e.

```
for i in range(0, len(__modes_names)):                                                                              #run through all available csv files
    with open(__csv_file_distance_arrays.format(__modes_names[i]), "r") as File:                                               
        csv_reader = csv.DictReader(File, delimiter=";")
        for line in csv_reader:                                                                                     #run through all lines
            for column in range(1, __numberoftps+1):                                                                #run through all columns
                if line["from\\to"] == __tps[column-1].get_name():                                                  #compare names of origin and destination
                    pass
                else:
                    for w in __ways:                                                                                #run through all ways
                        if w.get_name() == "way_{}_{}".format(line["from\\to"], __tps[column-1].get_name()):        #if way matches,
                            w.get_modes()[i].set_distance(int(line[__tps[column-1].get_name()]))                    #assign distance to way
                        else:
                            pass
```

In this case I do not need a return value because at this point of the program I've already instantiated a list of objects and call a method of those objects to save the variables I read from the CSV file.

Comment: Even without actually having a return, the function / method will still return.  When you have no explicit return `None` is returned.  So no, you do not need a return value if you are relying on side-effects alone.

Comment: also, if you're doing a `pass` in `else`, just don't mention the `else`

Comment: Also, `if moo: pass else: things` is better written `if not moo: things`